# Is there a way to get hold of the cancel event of the dialog boxes

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way in C# winform to alter the cancel button event of open or save dialog box.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by alter. You cannot edit the behavior of the ShowDialog, you can only handle the result returned and take the appropriate action. [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) is a sealed class, which means you cannot inherit from it and override behavior. If you truly need control at when the OpenFileDialog is shown, you'll need to create your own form to handle the necessary behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Look into DialogResult  and you'll find what you're looking for.

```
Dialog dialog = new <file save dialog>();

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
//   your code here
}
```

[DialogResult in Google](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&q=dialog+forms+c%23+dialogresult&meta=&aq=f&oq=)